# Eliminate [point] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

[point](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/point) has seven questions with almost as many tag definitions.  It has been used to mean restore point, mounting point, wireless access point, and location on an image.  There were no examples of data point, although that would also fit.  The tag has no definition and its varied usage eliminates any value as defining a category.

Recommendation: eliminate this tag so people will use more specific existing ones.  [access-point](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/access-point) and [wireless-access-point](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wireless-access-point) already exist.  Tags related to data points or locations on an image are probably not necessary.

I agree with Robotnik's comment about using the existing [mount](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mount) and [restore](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/restore) tags without creating additional tags for those now.  Since all uses are covered by existing tags, I've edited the question to just eliminate [point](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/point).

Comment: I agree with most, but I think mounting/restoring should just use [mount] and [restore] respectively (for now at least - at some point in the future we will probably decide to split those into OS-specific tags or similar)

Comment: I see your *point*.

Answer (score 1):

Why waiting? Obvious mistyped tags (tags created due the use of the space bar instead of dash) can be deleted without problems. I've go around and fixed the tags.

Comment: you lost me on this one.  I can't figure out how it relates.

Comment: I think he means that there was only 7 questions, (so it was obviously a tag created in error), and that he's just gone and removed them all, so we can mark this as [status-complete]